# iPhone keeps popping up Authentication Required

Tags: ios, iphone

Two questions here:

We pushed our IPA / Plist file to a website like normal to distribute our inhouse iphone app.  A few users (on newer iphone 6S and 7) can not seem to download the ipa file.  They can log into the web site but they get a quick double pop up of this screen.  Do you know why this could be?

Second user is having a more annoying problem.  Even after exiting safari on the iphone the authentication screen pops up in at random times.  They are not even in safari any more.  It's like the download is stuck in a never ending loop.  Pushing cancel, OK, putting in the right or wrong info - nothing helps. Any ideas how to stop this on their phone?

[image]

Comment: I have experienced the joy of that repeating popup in exactly the same situation you describe. Like, it popped up every few seconds to the point where I could almost not use my phone. I tried many things but the only thing that I remember working for me was to restore my phone from backup using iTunes.

Comment: is there a proxy or VPN setting on these two phones?

Comment: Try this site https://fir.im/ to distribute inHouse ipa

Comment: Hi - No VPN setting, no proxy.    (I am going to add the text of the pop up message here so it can be found by search engines.  "Authentication Required.  To access this site, you need to log in to this area on... Password will be sent securely.)